# How not to wrap the Tab Titles in Swipe View?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create swipe able views in android.
But since titles of my Tabs are longs they are getting wrapped to fit in single screen.

How to avoid the wrapping of titles and let the titles extend in one line even if the tab titles has to expand outside the current screen.

[Seen Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcTzq.png)

Comment: Do you want them to be ellipsized, or fully visible & scrollable?

Comment: I want them scroll able and fully visible , eg. if I have 10 tabs and titles of first 3 are so long that they will cover screen , then rest 7 titles should be visible as and when I do scroll toward them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an Android component for that called `PagerTitleStrip`: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#PagerTitleStrip

This will provide you fully-visible scrollable tabs.